# Interface with multiple paramenters

Tags: java, selenium

I created a utility class which has a few methods for checking elements on a webpage.  It is now time to refactor this these methods so that they belong to their own classes so that i can pass them around.

A couple of stubs for the methods in the class are below but their are many more with different parameters:

```
public boolean checkElementExistsByText(String key, String text) {}

public boolean checkElementText(String key, Predicate<String> predicate) {}

public boolean checkElementText(WebElement element, Predicate<String> predicate){}
```

I've tried creating the below interface:

```
interface CheckElementInterface {

boolean checkElement();

}
```

I'm having a problem with this because i'm not able to handle multiple parameters in the checkElement method, so ill have to pass them to the constructor for each class that implements this;

```
public class CheckedElementExistsByText implements CheckElementInterface{
    private final WebElement element;
    private final String text;

    public CheckedElementExistsByText(WebElement element, String text) {
        this.element = element;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkElement() {

    }
```

Is this the best way to do it, or is there a way i can pass multiple parameters to the checkElement() method?

Thanks

Comment: If those parameters are specific to each invocation, can't you just declare them as parameters in the interface?

Comment: This is the correct way to implement

Comment: @user7 The problem  is that the parameters differ for each method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create parametrized interface:

```
interface CheckElementInterface<T1, T2> {

 boolean checkElement(T1 elem1, T2 elem2);

}
```

Then you can create implementations, e.g.:

```
public class CheckedElementExistsByText implements CheckElementInterface<WebElement, String>{

@Override
public boolean checkElement(WebElement element, String text) {

}
```

---

**EDITED**:

The approach with parametrized interface rise a question how to obtain implementation of the interface for a concrete T1, T2. It requires additional feature in the implementation that helps to dispatch the "checkElement" request. E.g.

```
interface CheckElementInterfaceProvider {
    CheckElementInterface<T1, T2> getChecker(T1, T2);
}
```

and sample usage:

```
WebElement element;
String text;
checkElementInterfaceProvider.get(element, text).checkElement(element, text);
```

As I can see now: there is no need to have parameters in checkElementMethod as CheckElementProvider can act as a factory.

```
WebElement element;
String text;
checkElementInterfaceProvider.get(element, text).checkElement();
```

and modified CheckElementInterface (which is now almost the same as in your sample - only type parameters are added):

```
interface CheckElementInterface<T1, T2> {
    boolean checkElement();
}
public abstract class AbstractCheckElement<T1, T2> implements CheckElementInterface<T1, T2>{
    private final T1 e1;
    private final T2 e2;

    public AbstractCheckElement(T1 e1, T2 e2) {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
    }

}


 public class CheckedElementExistsByText implements AbstractCheckElement<WebElement, String>{
     public AbstractCheckElement(WebElement element, String text) {
        super(element, text);
     }
    @Override
    public boolean checkElement() {

    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need the two instance variables

Comment: @user7 I modify the solution ;)